# Вывести часть функционала десктопного приложения на сервер

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, веб-сервер

Есть программа на c# wpf. Возможно ли вывести часть программного кода за пределы скомпилированного .exe и подгружать со стороннего ресурса если это потребуется по ходу выполнения программы? Например в виде dll библиотеки хранящейся на сервере. Программа не знает о содержимом dll но при необходимости подключается к серверу, получает библиотеку и реализует её функционал.

Comment: В интернете пишут про использование [`Assembly.Load`, `Assembly.LoadFrom`, `Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx). В большинстве примеры можно найти для `Assembly.LoadFrom` в т.ч. на английском SO.

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо. буду изучать

Comment: Когда загрузите DLL из интернета, возможно, придётся убрать в альтернативном файловом потоке информацию о том, что файл загружен из Интернета.